# How to make gnuplot generate figures with smaller/fized size (Bytes)?

Tags: size, gnuplot, eps

I would like to avoid using `every` command since it simply discards data that, however, might be very important (like a spike for instance). I would like also to avoid posterior downsizing since this might lead to the deterioration of the text on the figure...

Is there a manner/option to force gnuplot generating files (eps) with maximum size?

Comment: That depends on the kind of plot you have.

Comment: @Christoph It is a 2D plot. Really simple plots...

Comment: No, you cannot reduce the size of general eps line plots. For the `image` and `pm3d` style there are ways, but otherwise: no. What about using pdf as output format?

Comment: @Christoph In fact am using epslatex terminal so to include latex equations....

Comment: You could try `set terminal cairolatex pdf`. But all that amounts only to a more compact representation of your data. If your data set is huge, you must probably do some kind of adaptive filter which keeps the spikes, but removes unnecessary data in regions where nothing happens (I don't have a suggestion here :)

Comment: I will try it. Thanks a lot @Christoph

Answer (score 0):

You'd need some adaptive compression on your data. Without actually knowing it, that's rather tough.

The `stats` command can tell you how many datapoints you actually have, and you can then adjust the `every` statement to a sensible value. Otherwise, you can use `smooth` to achieve a predefined (`set sample`) number of datapoints, or (if you have a sensible model for you data) you can do a `fit` and simply plot the fitted model function instead of you dataset.

If you specifically want outliers to show in the plot, this might be helpful:

```
fit f(x) data via *parameter*
plot f(x), data using ((abs($2-f($1)) > threshold) ? $2 : NaN)
```

It plots a fit to your dataset, and all actual datapoints that deviate from the fit by more than *threshold*.